# Calling or using oracle array package in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, plsql-package

I want to calling oracle array package in oracle apex page process.
My package "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SBPA.DPG_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT AS

/*..........................................................................
Program Purpose : SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT_ENTRY
Process Execution Time :

Generate By     : Morshed
Generate Date : 27-Feb-2020
Modifyed Date :
.....................................................................*/

TYPE RefCursor is REF CURSOR;

TYPE Array_Item_Sub_Id IS TABLE OF SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT.ITEM_SUB_ID % TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE Array_Item_Sub_Code IS TABLE OF SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT.ITEM_SUB_CODE % TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE Array_Item_Sub_Desc IS TABLE OF SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT.ITEM_SUB_DESC % TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE Array_Item_Cat_Code IS TABLE OF SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT.ITEM_CAT_CODE % TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE Array_RowStatus IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE DPD_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT (O_Status OUT NUMBER,
P_Item_Sub_Id IN Array_Item_Sub_Id,
P_Item_Sub_Code IN Array_Item_Sub_Code,
P_Item_Sub_Desc IN Array_Item_Sub_Desc,
P_Item_Cat_Code IN Array_Item_Cat_Code,
P_RowStatus IN Array_RowStatus,
P_USER VARCHAR2);

PROCEDURE DPD_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT_GRID (Cur_Data OUT RefCursor);

END DPG_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT;
/"

And Package body "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SBPA.DPG_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT AS

/*..........................................................................
Program Purpose : SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT_ENTRY
Process Execution Time :

Generate By     : Morshed
Generate Date : 27-Feb-2020
Modifyed Date :
.....................................................................*/

PROCEDURE DPD_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT (O_Status OUT NUMBER,
P_Item_Sub_Id IN Array_Item_Sub_Id,
P_Item_Sub_Code IN Array_Item_Sub_Code,
P_Item_Sub_Desc IN Array_Item_Sub_Desc,
P_Item_Cat_Code IN Array_Item_Cat_Code,
P_RowStatus IN Array_RowStatus,
P_USER VARCHAR2) IS

```
V_DataType     VARCHAR2(20) :='ITEM_SUBCAT_SAVE';
V_ErrDesc   VARCHAR2(500);
```

BEGIN

```
/*O_Status :=1;*/

FOR I IN P_Item_Sub_Desc.FIRST..P_Item_Sub_Desc.LAST
LOOP
  
        IF P_RowStatus(I)=1 THEN
                    
            INSERT INTO SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT 
            (ITEM_SUB_ID, ITEM_SUB_CODE, ITEM_SUB_DESC, ITEM_CAT_CODE, STATUS, CREATE_DATE, CREATE_BY) VALUES
            (SBPA_ITEM_SUB_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'ITMSC-'||LPAD(SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CODE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,4,'0'),P_Item_Sub_Desc(I),P_Item_Cat_Code(I),'A',SYSDATE,P_USER);
                        
        ELSIF P_RowStatus(I)=2 THEN
                    
            UPDATE SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT SET
            ITEM_SUB_DESC=P_Item_Sub_Desc(I),
            Item_Cat_Code=P_Item_Cat_Code(I),
            UPDATE_BY=P_User, 
            UPDATE_DATE =SYSDATE
            WHERE Item_Sub_Code=P_Item_Sub_Code(I);
                    
        ELSIF P_RowStatus(I)=3 THEN
            
            DELETE FROM SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT
            WHERE Item_Sub_Code=P_Item_Sub_Code(I);              
                    
        END IF;
    
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
```

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK;

/* O_Status :=0;*/
V_ErrDesc:=SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,500);

```
INSERT INTO SBPA_ERROR_LOG
```

(RUN_ID, DATA_TYPE, ERROR_DESC, STATUS, RUN_DATE, RUN_BY) VALUES
(SBPA_RUN_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,V_DataType,V_ErrDesc,'E',SYSDATE,P_User);

```
COMMIT;
```

END DPD_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT;

PROCEDURE DPD_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT_GRID (Cur_Data OUT RefCursor) IS

BEGIN

```
OPEN CUR_DATA FOR
SELECT ITEM_SUB_ID, ITEM_SUB_CODE, ITEM_SUB_DESC,S.ITEM_CAT_CODE,C.ITEM_CAT_DESC FROM SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT S,SBPA_ITEM_CAT C
WHERE S.ITEM_CAT_CODE=C.ITEM_CAT_CODE
ORDER BY ITEM_SUB_ID DESC;
```

END DPD_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT_GRID;

END DPG_SBPA_ITEM_SUB_CAT;
/"
This database code. So how can i call this package in oracle apex tabular form. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

(1) Create a button, so the processing(DML) will be performed on click of the button.

(2) Button Action -> Submit Page.

(3) Create a page Process

```
Point -> Processing. 
Tabular Form -> Select your tabular form.
Pl/SQL Code ->  Begin 
                package_name.procedure_name(parameters);  
                END;
```

(4) When Button Pressed: Select the created button.

(5) Execution Scope: For Created and Modified rows.